# Python3 Pandas - transform and return a series of the new price column

Tags: python, pandas, transform, series

I was working on the question that asks me to perform several operations using split-apply-combine.
I got answers for most of them except the last question.

Here is the last question:

If the maximum price in a category is more than $3.00, reduce all prices in that category by 10%. Return a Series of the new price column.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
grocery = pd.DataFrame({'category':['produce', 'produce', 'meat',
                                'meat', 'meat', 'cheese', 'cheese'],
                    'item':['celery', 'apple', 'ham', 'turkey',  'lamb',
                            'cheddar', 'brie'],
                    'price':[.99, .49, 1.89, 4.34, 9.50, 6.25, 8.0]})
grouped = grocery.groupby('category')
answer = grouped.transform(lambda x: 0.9 * x if np.max(x) > 3 else x)
```

I think I got the part of reduce all prices in the category by 10%.
However, I'm having a trouble that how can I return my 'answer' as a series of the new price column.

When I submit what I have ('answer') to submission page, values for the price are correct but it is not considered as a series. I know pd.Series but not sure how can I convert this to Series here.

Can someone give me an insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign to new column because [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) return Series with same size like original `DataFrame`, also for general solution is necessary specify column `price` after `groupby` for process only this column:

```
grouped = grocery.groupby('category')['price']
print (type(grouped.transform(lambda x: 0.9 * x if np.max(x) > 3 else x)))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print (grouped.transform(lambda x: 0.9 * x if np.max(x) > 3 else x))
0    0.990
1    0.490
2    1.701
3    3.906
4    8.550
5    5.625
6    7.200
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

If need assign to column `price`:

```
grocery['price'] = grouped.transform(lambda x: 0.9 * x if np.max(x) > 3 else x)
print (grocery)
  category     item  price
0  produce   celery  0.990
1  produce    apple  0.490
2     meat      ham  1.701
3     meat   turkey  3.906
4     meat     lamb  8.550
5   cheese  cheddar  5.625
6   cheese     brie  7.200
```

And solution with [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
grocery = (grocery.assign(price = lambda x: x.groupby('category')['price']
                                             .transform(lambda x: 0.9 * x 
                                                                  if np.max(x) > 3 
                                                                  else x)))
```

Comment: hi jezrael, is there any way to just assign price?
Here is what I got for hint message.
"remember, this question asks you to return a Series; as such, at a certain point we're only interested in price."

Comment: @DanielKim - Just add to answer.